# Getting mouse coordinates in SDK first-time right-click

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

For an SDK add-on, I am trying to detect, on right-click, the closest page anchor (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360624/document-caretpositionfrompoint-grabbing-too-high/24406145#24406145)).

Since JavaScript apparently has no way to query the mouse coordinates without first creating a mouse event listener, and since I don't want an expensive mouseover listener running all of the time on every single page! (and polling to rebuild a mouse listener is ugly and not fully accurate anyways), I was hoping I could get the mouse coordinates from a click event. Unfortunately, although `self.on('click'` does fire:

1. This event is without an event object from which mouse coordinates could be obtained
2. Adding a normal `window.addEventListener('click',...` listener doesn't actually get fired in the SDK content script with the first menu selection for some reason (it does fire subsequently, however).

Here is my workaround, but I want to fire on the current exact coordinates, not the coordinates of the node:

```
var x, y;
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.button === 2) {
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    }
}, true);

self.on('click', function (node) {
    if (!x) { // Since this is not showing the first time, we fire on the node (which is specifically an element, not a text node), though we really want the real clientX and clientY where the mouse is, not this simulation based on where the element is
        node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
            button: 2
        }));
    }
    // Use document.caretPositionFromPoint with x and y to determine location of text
```

Is there any other way to get the actual mouse coordinates?

Comment: I cannot really reproduce this. The `addEventListener("click", ...)` always fires before `self.on("click", ...)` when I tried it. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: For me, the problem only occurs for the very first attempt on loading the page. Reloading the page causes the same thing to happen again: the first attempt fails to detect correctly (detects too high by going through the `if (!x)` workaround due to the missing click event), but subsequent context menu invocations do work properly. Tested against SDK 1.16 with FF 31.0.

Comment: You're testing using the code from https://github.com/brettz9/jump-to-anchor , right?

Comment: Right...in the current master branch... Sometimes it goes to anchor 2.3.2 , but that is still too high--if clicking in section 2.3.3, it should go to 2.3.3

Comment: and when I added logging, nothing showed up in the `window.addEventListener('click'` code until after the first attempt...

Comment: Nope, cannot reproduce on Fx31 OSX, having tested `cfx run` and a fresh profile + `cfx xpi`. Maybe something OS/platform specific?

Comment: Maybe---I'm on Windows...Also trying with either `cfx run` or `cfx xpi` (just now also on a new profile).

Comment: Maybe a viable work-around could be to not immediately execute code in `self.on("click", ...)` but instead issue a `setTimeout(code, 0)` to wait for the current event queue to finish dispatching?

Comment: Nice idea but even 10,000 ms didn't do the trick... the only reported logging of the click was the one caused by my simulated event after 10 secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually query the mouse coordinates without a mouse listener.

This page has a bunch of examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries

It has to be done on per OS basis though as it uses JS-Ctypes. If you're worried about performance don't fear at all. You can use the code asynchronously via `ChromeWorker`s

Comment: Fascinating--would have been nice if it could have been without an OS dependency, but that is quite cool, thanks!

Comment: :O @nmaier got out thunk by a new user!! props man, may be your first and last time tho :P

Comment: FTR, although this solution does indeed get coordinates nicely, in my case I needed the coordinates at the time the user clicked down to get the menu, not at the time the user clicked the specific item (as is the time the add-on script can get notified). I worked around the issue by associating a pageMod to the cm (as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/11768820/271577 ) and the pageMod has no trouble with the `click` event.

Comment: Maybe a `postMessage` in the "context" event would have worked to get the coordinates at the right time, but I needed a way to communicate back to the content anyways (and nicer not to need OS-specific code).